# VBA & Selenium - Proxy doesn't really connect

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to setting a proxy rotation to scrape info from google.
I use VBA (on Excel) + Selenium + Chrome.

Nothing seems to work.
I tried every browser.
I tried xmlHttp.

The code runs smoothly but when I check the ip, it's still mine and not the proxy one.

Here my code:

```
Sub checkProxies()
Dim bot As New Selenium.ChromeDriver
Dim cell As Range
Dim myproxy As String
Dim url As String
Dim lastrow As Integer

lastrow = shProxies.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

bot.Start

For Each cell In shProxies.Range("A2:A" & lastrow)
    myproxy = cell.Value
    bot.proxy.SetHttpProxy myproxy
    bot.Get "https://www.google.com/search?q=check+my+ip"
    cell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.Color = vbGreen
Next cell

bot.Quit
End sub
```

I have a list of proxies in Excel, I'm trying to change them dynamically and check if they're working.

I also tried with one single proxy, still doesn't work.

Any clue how to solve this?

Many Thanks

Comment: The code is working for me. How do you type the proxies in column A?

Comment: Thanks YasserKhalil, if it's working to you it's a good news!
I type it like: xxx.xx.xx.xx:XX
Am I wrong in this piece?

P.S.: I got another solution to my task, but it's still good to know how to work with proxies, i got an headache yesterday with them!

Comment: Great. Can you share the solution that you have now ..? I am interested in this issue like you.

Comment: Basically, i overcome the captcha problem not using proxy but adding a Wait time: google pops up the captcha page if the frequency of your requests exceed a certain limit.
I'll share the full solution with code in a link tomorrow.
Can you please tell me how did you type the proxy link?

Comment: Exactly as you did `xxx.xx.xx.xx:XX`. The code works but the IP didn't change as I expected.

Comment: Yeah, that's why i was asking, if you check the IP nothing really happen...